# Interactive UINavigationController transition

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

Is there a way to enable interactive edge-swipe-back transition in [Motion](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Motion)? I've set `motionNavigationTransitionType` to `.autoReverse(presenting: .slide(direction: .left))` and this works when you pop the view controller, but I want to be able to interactively transition between the two view controllers.